# Is it correct to say to a child "This rubber band is too tight on your wrist and it may prevent your blood circulation. So, take it off"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I have read this article "[Elastic band removed from little boy's wrist after his flesh grows around it](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/peoplesdaily/article-3646297/Elastic-band-growing-inside-flesh-four-year-old-boy-s-WRIST.html)"

Some children put very tight rubber band on their wrist, which may prevent their blood circulation at their wrists and they don't even notice it until it is too late.

Is it correct to say  to a child "**This rubber band is too tight on your wrist and it may prevent your blood circulation. So, take it off**"?

Comment: It's [way more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=26&content=prevent+blood+circulation%2Crestrict+blood+circulation&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprevent%20blood%20circulation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crestrict%20blood%20circulation%3B%2Cc0) to say ***restrict** blood circulation* rather than ***prevent***. But "blood circulation" (and the implications of restricting it) are pretty obscure words / concepts to bandy about with a child. And the example with "flesh growing around it" sounds like it's in a completely different league.

Comment: Are you asking about grammatical correctness, practicality, morality, or etiquette?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - +1 for the “obscure concept” statement. I might just tell the child to, “Take off the rubber band. It’s bad for you.” Or, “That thing will cut off the blood to your hand. Then, we will have to cut the hand off of you.” It depends on the age of the child, the severity of the situation, and my relationship with the child.

Comment: It's medically correct, but it is not child friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[parents' bracelet concerns](https://dfw.cbslocal.com/2010/11/01/popular-childrens-bracelet-concerns-parents/)

From: **Dr. Linley McAnalley,** a family friend, saw Huck’s hand and said he was lucky his mother pulled the bands off.

> “The bands, if they’re worn too tight for too long, can create a tourniquet type effect and can interfere with the **blood flow into
> and out of the hand**,” McAnalley said. “The blood gets stagnant in
> the hand; blood clots can form.”
>
> This is a scare 8-year-old Chris Palmier knows all too well. Chris
> also slept in too many tight bands. His mother, Donnita Palmier, said
> she was taking him to school when she looked down at his hand.
>
> “It was monstrous! It was huge,” she said. “It was like, from a freak
> show! It was five times bigger than the other hand.”
>
> A doctor told the family to watch the hand for three days and come in
> if the swelling remained. **On the fourth day, the blood flow
> returned.**

Conclusion: Take that rubber band off your wrist because it will stop your blood flow

Answer (score 1):

This is once again a correct but far too long-winded approach to English.  Another factor that you seem to miss is that the other person can talk English back to you.

So, what does a parent say to a child:

> Take the rubber band off your wrist!

And then one of several things might happen:

The child might do it. And this is fine.  Or the child might ask "why". Or the child might say "no". Or the child might look blankly, because they don't understand.

Now if the child doesn't take the rubber band off, you need to ***communicate***.  The child doesn't care about whether your English is grammatically well formed. You need to explain **in terms that the child will understand**.  And you know best how much your child understands.  Remember this is **your** child.

Comment: Right, no one uses adult language with a kid. It will stop your blood flow.